# What language technique is "I am gone though I am here"

Tags: literary-techniques

I am writing an essay about Shakespeare's 'Much Ado About Nothing' and I was wondering what language technique is used in "I am gone though I am here". Is it a juxtaposition, oxymoron or what?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a paradox.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox

Other paradoxes involve false statements ("impossible is not a word in my vocabulary", a simple paradox) or half-truths and the resulting biased assumptions. This form is common in howlers.
For example, consider a situation in which a father and his son are driving down the road. The car crashes into a tree and the father is killed. The boy is rushed to the nearest hospital where he is prepared for emergency surgery. On entering the surgery suite, the surgeon says, "I can't operate on this boy. He's my son."
The apparent paradox is caused by a hasty generalization, for if the surgeon is the boy's father, the statement cannot be true. The paradox is resolved if it is revealed that the surgeon is a woman — the boy's mother.

Based on the page, the false assumption that "I am gone though I am here" refers to physical location both times (hasty generalization), could qualify the statement as a paradox.

---

It is definitely a contradiction. It doesn't follow logic i.e "One cannot say of something that it is and that it is not in the same respect and at the same time."

---

"I am gone though I am here" is definitely a contradiction and it may be a very basic paradox if you're willing to stretch your interpretation.

Comment: A paradox is an apparent contradiction, not a true contradiction. As you say, the use of different interpretations (one metaphorical, one literal) for "I am gone though I am here", as Shakespeare intends, reveals that the sentence is not illogical. This probably qualifies as an oxymoron (a succinctly expressed paradox).

Comment: Thankyou, I also discussed this with my English teacher and he believes it is a paradox as well.